# Does PHP exec() create processes or threads

Tags: php

I do not know the inner workings of php exec() but I like to know if it create processes or threads for execution of external command.

Comment: You might take a look at the source code http://lxr.php.net

Comment: from the PHP man page it seems like at least on some operating systems it's a process, but of course this is implementation-specific. Can you say which OS you are interested in?

Comment: Ah, [this](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/standard/exec.c#82) indicates that it creates a new process

Answer (score 2):

When you call exec php does not create a thread, it creats a new child process.
more information here [PHP exec() performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277910/php-exec-performance)

Answer (score 0):

It *has* to be a process. You can't launch a new shell in a thread. Threads are delineations of a single process: you cannot start a *new* program without creating a *new* process.